# Limits - generalizing formula

Tags: analysis, limits

I'm confused with this: I need to generalize the formula $\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ = $ \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n}{\lim_{n\to\infty } b_n} $  so that it can be applied even in exceptional cases.

I see that the exceptional case is when $b_n=0$. Shall I use the formula $\lim_{n\to\infty } (1+\frac {a}{n})^n=e^a$ ?

Comment: If $b_n=0$ a finite number of times the limit is still well defined.

Comment: So is there a different case which is not applicable in this formula? I was convinced about zero.

Comment: Also when both limits are $\;\pm\infty\;$ you cannot generalize

Comment: Our teacher told us that${+\infty}$ has a different meaning than ${\infty}$